# How does a RISC-V processor handle a timer interrupt when running in S mode with mstatus.MIE=0 and mideleg=0?

Tags: riscv

Here is an inference, I don’t know if it is correct:

- Assume that the processor is running in S mode, mstatus.MIE=0, mideleg=0,.
- Then a timer interrupt occurs. The processor will still handle this interrupt and do so in M mode, MPIE=MIE=0, MPP=0b01 (S mode).
- When the timer interrupt is processed, the mret instruction is executed, MIE=MPIE=0, and the processor returns to S mode.

I wonder if the above is a correct inference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, correct. If not delegated interrupt will be targeted to M mode. When in lower privilege, interrupt of higher privilege mode is always taken regardless of mstatus.MIE. But M-mode firmware can disable the interrupt using mie csr. Which is not a normal case and interrupt will be lost until enabled again.

From the spec:

> An interrupt i will trap to M-mode (causing the privilege mode to
> change to M-mode) if all of the following are true:
>
> (a) either the current privilege mode is M and the MIE bit in the
> mstatus register is set, or the current privilege mode has less
> privilege than M-mode;
>
> (b) bit i is set in both mip and mie; and
>
> (c) if register mideleg exists, bit i is not set in mideleg.

Condition a is satisfied as we either need to be in M mode and with mie.MTIE set or we need to be in lower privilege level in which case interrupts of higher privilege level are always taken regardless of mstatus.mie bit.

Condition b needs to meet as well. mie.MTIP needs to be set.

Cond c is again satisfied in your case.